# Getting an error "No date part in '' found." while creating an product programatically

Tags: product, programmatically, create

I am trying to create an virtual product programatically by using below code.When I execute this script from root of the store I am getting an error :

> No date part in '' found.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$product
->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
->setAttributeSetId(4) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
->setTypeId('virtual') //product type
->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
->setSku('test') //SKU
->setName('Test Product') //product name
->setWeight(4.0000)
->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
->setTaxClassId(0) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE) //catalog and search visibility
->setPrice(0) //price in form 11.22
->setCost(0) //price in form 11.22
->setDescription('This is a long description')
->setShortDescription('This is a short description')

->setStockData(array(
                   'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                   'manage_stock'=>0, //manage stock
                   'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                   'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                   'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                   'qty' => 999 //qty
               )
);

 try{ 
    $product->save();

  }catch(Exception $e){
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think that there is a problem with param passed to `setCreatedAt()` method. Try to remove it (or change `strtotime('now')` to `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`) and see what happens.

Comment: I faced the exact issue and solved by following @SeStro 's solution. Thanks.